# Como criar um executável .jar?

Tags: java, compilação

Tem como compilar um projeto java no **eclipse**, se sim, como?

Senão, como eu compilo um projeto em **Java**?

---

Eu consegui transformar o código em .jar pelo eclipse. Só que quando clico para executá-lo, ele simplesmente, não abre.

Dei uma pesquisada de como de compilar por cmd, usando javac. Eu até consegui *compilar*, mais criar um executável .jar eu não consegui.

Bom, minha dúvida é, como criar um executável .jar a partir de um projeto?

Comment: Aqui tem uma explicação bem completa: http://luizricardo.org/2013/11/instalando-configurando-e-usando-o-eclipse-kepler/

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Higor, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! O Eclipse é uma IDE (Ambiente Integrado de Desenvolvimento) e um de seus objetivos é justamente automatizar a compilação dos projetos. Imagino que talvez você esteja enfrentando algum problema em particular, então sugiro que seja mais específico na sua pergunta de modo que possamos lhe ajudar melhor. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Mas é claro, uma das funções dele é essa, se você já tem o SDK instalado e o projeto importado para o eclipse, basta clicar com o botão direito do mouse em cima do projeto > `Run As` > `Java Application`.

Answer (score 0):

Tente exportar como Runnable JAR File:
`Export > Java >Runnable JAR File`

Answer (score 0):

Vá em: **> Files > Export > Runnable Jar File**. Escreva o lugar onde você quer que apareça e escolha o arquivo **Main**, depois clique em **Export**.

Caso não saiba qual é o arquivo **main**, é o que tem a função:

```
public static void main(String args[]) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente o IDE automatiza isso para você, eu uso o NetBeans e sempre que você constrói o projeto ele gera o jar, que fica na pasta dist do projeto. No caso do Eclipse creio que ele também faça isso de alguma forma(desconheço). Agora se quiser fazer isso no CMD é da seguinte forma:

1- Crie um arquivo manifest.txt no diretório do pacote que contém toda a sua aplicação com o seguinte conteúdo(supondo que sua classe principal esteja no pacote app.main e tenha o nome MainWindow):

Main-Class: app.main.MainWindow

 Name: app/main/MainWindow.class

 Java-Bean: true

- A primeira linha 'Main-Class: ...' é onde você define o pacote da sua classe principal(classe que contém a função main), como se fosse uma importação 'app.main.Window'.
- A segunda linha 'Name: ...' informa qual o diretório da sua classe principal, a partir do diretório do arquivo manifest.txt, se ele estiver no mesmo diretório do pacote principal, a primeira linha será semelhante a segunda, a diferença é que você usa '/' ao invés de '.' e tem que especificar a extensão '.class' da classe principal.
- A terceira linha 'Java-Bean: true' informa que você quer usar a opção java bean.

2- Abra o CMD e navegue até o diretório do arquivo manifest.txt, então digite:

jar cfm NomeDaAplicação.jar manifest.txt app

Assim você especifica o nome da sua aplicação, inclui o arquivo de manifesto que faz algumas especificações importantes sobre seu arquivo (.jar), e define o que estará contido no (.jar), neste caso o pacote principal que contém tudo é o pacote app. 
Está pronto seu jar!